# Configurar Servidor Web Virtual

Tags: dns, lado-do-servidor

Como faço para configurar um subdomínio para que acesse os arquivos dentro do meu servidor sobre uma url de terceiro?

por exemplo, tenho um sistema que está rodando em:

```
https://sistema.meudominio.com.br/
```

para cada "novo cliente" gostaria de criar algo assim:

```
https://consultas.dominiodocliente.com.br
```

dessa forma acessando o endereço `https://consultas.dominiodocliente.com.br` ele permanece no subdomínio dele porem acessando os arquivos do meu servidor?

Servidor:
Apache 2.4.34
SO linux

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você está confundindo conceitos, porque você falou de DNS e mais provavelmente a solução do seu problema reside na configuração do servidor Web. Mas as opções são as seguintes:

1) DNS CNAME - você pode cadastrar um CNAME consultas.dominiodocliente.com.br que aponte para sistema.meudominio.com.br. Mas este procedimento não vai "esconder" o segundo nome, é mais útil quando se tem um domínio velho que deve ser redirecionado para um domínio novo.

2) Servidor Web virtual. Um servidor Web pode atender por mais de um domínio, então no DNS dominiodocliente você pode configurar a máquina para o IP do seu servidor, e na configuração do seu servidor Web, você direciona conforme o nome. Neste caso o nome sistema.meudominio.com.br é irrelevante, ele é apenas mais um domínio servido pelo Web server.

Cada servidor Web (NGINX, Apache, etc.) tem configuração diferente para múltiplos servidores virtuais.

Comment: eu acho que você já me deu um norte pra começar, eu nem sei como isso funciona da parte tecnica, porem já fiz essa configuração para esse proposito de uma plataforma web que contratei (minha hospedagem aponta pro servidor deles onde roda a aplicação), porem não sei tecnicamente como isso funciona, e como agora tenho um sistema web eu achei interessante, se não for abusar da sua ajuda, poderia me indicar artigos? ou algo para pesquisa? muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Você precisa especificar na pergunta qual o servidor Web que usa, aí alguém pode expandir a resposta e colocar como ficaria a configuração, ou apontar uma referência.